# java.lang.IllegalStateException using jprofiler launch

Tags: jprofiler

When trying to profile a java app I get the following error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.arinc.aops.javafx.app.AopsAppFactory`

The app runs fine in Eclipse and I can profile it using the jprofiler attach option, I just can't do a launch without getting the error.

Comment: Please contact support for a new build which may fix this issue